# How to get all Items from JObject?

Tags: c#, json, string

I have a loop and get several times a JObject with up to 500 items like the following.
[image]

items looks like the following only with more informations

```
"{items:[{'id':'1', 'name':'DISP_1'}, {'id':'2','name':'DISP_2'}, {'id':'3','name':'sa'}, {'id':'4','name':'DISP_'}]}";
```

My Question is, how can I get all informations in "items" and save them in a string, respectively if I loop 3 times and have for example 1500 different items, how can I save all items of each iteration step in one string or list?

Comment: Any particular reason your not just de serializing into a typed enumerable?  There are plenty of tools out there for converting json into models, https://json2csharp.com/ for instance.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to get a value from LINQ to JSON is to use the index methods on JObject/JArray

```
        using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.Linq;

        namespace JObjectApp
        {
            class Program
            {
                static void Main(string[] args)
                {

                    string json = "{items:[{'id':'1', 'name':'DISP_1'}, {'id':'2','name':'DISP_2'}, {'id':'3','name':'sa'}, {'id':'4','name':'DISP_'}]}";

                    dynamic temp = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(json);

                    JArray items = temp.items;

                    IList<string> item = items.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToList();

                }

            }
        }
```

[click here for Detail](https://howtodevelop.net/article/32/how-to-use-jobject-in-csharp)

[image]